# Класс Object и аргументы

Tags: java, объекты

Изучаю класс Object:
Множество методов класса ArrayList используют основной полиморфический тип Object. Поскольку каждый класс в языке Java - потомок класса Object, эти методы могут принимать все что угодно! (написано в книге Изучаем Java (Кэти Сиерра)

Хотелось бы узнать как так всё что угодно? Подскажите какие-нибудь примеры вроде бы прилично знаком с этим, но вот всё что угодно смущает

Comment: любой класс можно "поместить" в Object, так как он родитель всех классов в Java, соответственно и в коллекцию можно поместить любой объект любого класса (если она не типизирована) и вызывать методы коллекции для такого класса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все объекты в Java наследуются от `Object`. Вы это сами можете увидеть, даже в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Если взять ваш

```
java.lang.Object
    java.util.AbstractCollection<E>
        java.util.AbstractList<E>
            java.util.ArrayList<E>
```

Собственно вот так.

И, если вы хотите поместить в ArrayList, то вам лишь необходимо сделать, что-то типа

```
Object o1="Hi";
Object o2=2;
Object o3=new Object();
List<Object> list=Arrays.asList(o1,o2,o3);
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output**

[Hi, 2, java.lang.Object@18e8568]

Comment: А если без дженериков как это сделать?

Comment: @MikeMclaren, вы можете их убрать и без них сделать. Просто с ними, вы явно сообщаете программе, что в `List` будет лежать Object.
Можно еще и так)
`        List list=Arrays.asList((Object)o1,(Object)o2,(Object)o3,(Object)new String("asd"),new String("да-да"));`

Comment: Cпасибо большое!

Comment: @MikeMclaren, пожалуйста )